# Adding latitude and longitude around image saved in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, latitude-longitude, grids-graticules

Is there a way to add latitude and longitude around an image in ArcMap when you are in layout view?

I have attached an example of what I mean. I would like to do this so people looking at a saved image of a map can know the general location of the image.

[image: Latitude and Longitude around image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try [Adding a graticule](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/page-layouts/adding-a-graticule.htm).  The preceding link provides:

> the steps you can take to add a graticule to your map layout using
>   **Grids and Graticules Wizard**. For more information on Grids and Graticules Wizard, see [A quick tour of the Grids and Graticules
>   Wizard](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/page-layouts/a-quick-tour-of-the-grids-and-graticules-wizard.htm).

A graticule can display latitude and longitude values around a data frame in Layout View, and does so by default.

For this to work the image within the data frame will need to be correctly georeferenced.

Answer (score -1):

You can add a reference grid to your layout using instructions found here:  https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/page-layouts/adding-a-reference-grid.htm

These instructions show you how to make grids, graticule, or reference grids using the coordinate reference system of your choice including latitudes and longitudes.  The link is for ArcGIS 10.3 but if you go to this link you can choose any ESRI version.

Comment: Why a reference grid (usually in meters or feet) and not a graticule (in lat/long)?  Also, I think the latest documentation would be more helpful than that of 10.3, just in case it’s been enhanced/corrected in any regard.